# PHP: Update multiple MySQL fields in single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am basically just trying to update multiple values in my table. What would be the best way to go about this? Here is the current code:

```
$postsPerPage = $_POST['postsPerPage'];
$style = $_POST['style'];

mysql_connect ("localhost", "user", "pass") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("db");

mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET postsPerPage = $postsPerPage WHERE id = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

The other update I want to include is:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET style = $style WHERE id = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Add your multiple columns with comma separations:

```
UPDATE settings SET postsPerPage = $postsPerPage, style= $style WHERE id = '1'
```

However, you're not sanitizing your inputs??  This would mean any random hacker could destroy your database.  See this question: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Also, is style a number or a string?  I'm assuming a string, so it would need to be quoted.

Answer (score 6):

Comma separate the values:

```
UPDATE settings SET postsPerPage = $postsPerPage, style = $style WHERE id = '1'"
```

Comment: OK, but no upvote because you forgot to point out the glaring flaws in this approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pdo, it will look like

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname = :firstname, lastname = :lastname WHERE id= :id";
$query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute(array(':firstname' => $firstname, ':lastname' => $lastname, ':id' => $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use:

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$sql = "UPDATE `some_table` SET `txid`= '$txid', `data` = '$data' WHERE `wallet` = '$wallet'";
if ($mysqli->query($sql, $con)) {
    print "wallet $wallet updated";
}else{
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $con->error);
}
$con->close();
```