# MySQL Multiple UPDATE: many queries equivalent without foreach()

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I have settings table (ID,param,name) with lots of settings for site. When I try to update thats settings, and I do that (personally for each parameter):

```
...$sql = "UPDATE settings SET `value` = ? WHERE param = ?";
$DB->query($sql, $_POST['SITE_NAME'], 'SITE_NAME');
$sql = "UPDATE settings SET `value` = ? WHERE param = ?";
$DB->query($sql, $_POST['SITE_DESC'], 'SITE_DESC');...
```

Etc. How I can update data in my table without multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` only supports one `WHERE` condition, so it is not suitable for what you want. However, if you have the IDs of the rows (I assume ID is the primary key), you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO settings (ID, value) VALUES (id1, value1) (id2, value2) ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)
```

Comment: Like INSERT INTO settings (param, value) VALUES ("SITE_NAME", "http://www.com"), ("SITE_DESC", "aaa") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)?

Comment: That would work if `param` is a primary key or defined as `UNIQUE`. What this statement does is try to insert the tuples following the word `VALUES` into the table, but if that would fail because of a duplicate key violation, it executes the `UPDATE` part instead. See the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the syntax for the UPDATE statement

generally you can write

```
UPDATE <table> SET <col1> = <val1>, <col2> = <val2> ... WHERE ...
```

[Similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254173/php-update-multiple-mysql-fields-in-single-query)