# How to update multiple columns in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Here i am trying to update update multiple column values in mysql table using php.

```
$product_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['product_id']);
$product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['product_name']);
$product_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['product_category']);

$sql = "UPDATE product_list (product_name, product_category, product_price,product_description,product_size_category) VALUES ('$product_name', '$product_category', '$product_price', '$product_description', '$size_category')";
}"
```

i have 5 column values to be updated in table, i am using variable to save data and using that variable want to update the values in table how can i do that?

Comment: So what's the problem you're having?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Update multiple MySQL fields in single query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254173/php-update-multiple-mysql-fields-in-single-query)

Comment: your query is insert query. not update query. Use `update table_name` set `column_name` = 'value'

Comment: @Mithun Please check your query. I think, you are confused with INSERT and UPDATE query. Refer the UPDATE query syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 $sql = "UPDATE `product_list` SET 
       `product_name` = '$product_name', 
       `product_category` = '$product_category', 
       `product_price` = '$product_price', 
       `product_description` = '$product_description', 
       `product_size_category` = '$size_category' 
  where clause..... (if required) ";
```

Answer (score 5):

Try like this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_list SET product_name='".$product_name."',product_category='".$product_category."',product_price='".$product_price."',product_description='".$product_description."',size_category='".$size_category."' WHERE product_id=".$product_id;
```

Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 4):

Update SQL query, see following method:

`Update database_tablename SET column_name1 = column_value1 , column_name2 = column_value2`

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_list SET product_name='".$product_name."',product_category='".$product_category."',product_price='".$product_price."',product_description='".$product_description."',size_category='".$size_category."'";
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually won't help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up query syntax between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries, the `UPDATE` syntax is ;

```
UPDATE TABLE SET col1 = val1, col2=val2... WHERE col1 = val
```

You shall use the `UPDATE` query as follows :

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_list SET product_name = '$product_name', 
product_category = '$product_category' WHERE product_id = $product_id";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query must be something like this :

```
"UPDATE product_list 
set 
product_name='$product_name', 
product_category ='$product_category', 
product_price='$product_price',
product_description='$product_description',
product_size_category='$size_category'
where product_id='$product_id'
"
```

1. make sure you define the variable you need like $size_category etc, cause i didn't see it.
2. use conditions like where to update specific record