# Updating multiple Mysql rows using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi guys before I start I want to point out that I have been through the following links and more

[How to update multiple columns in mysql using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438206/how-to-update-multiple-columns-in-mysql-using-php)
[PHP: Update multiple MySQL fields in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254173/php-update-multiple-mysql-fields-in-single-query)

I am trying to update a few rows in my database, this is my code:

```
$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_client_info WHERE UCODE=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['btn-update-data']))
        {
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            $cpass = $_POST['confirm-pass'];
            $name = $_POST['firstname'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $email = $_POST['billingemail'];
            $cell = $_POST['Cell'];

            if($cpass!==$pass)
            {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-block'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                        <strong>Sorry!</strong>  Input Does Not Match. Make sure the details match. 
                        </div>";
            }
            else
            {


                $stmt = $user->runQuery("UPDATE `tbl_client_info` SET 
                    firstname =:name, 
                    lastname =:lastname, 
                    email =:billingemail, 
                    Cell =:cell, 
                    password=:upass, 
                    where UCODE=:uid");

                    $stmt->bindparam(":firstname",$name);
                    $stmt->bindparam(":lastname",$lastname);
                    $stmt->bindparam(":billingemail",$email);
                    $stmt->bindparam(":Cell",$cell);
                    $stmt->bindparam(":upass",$pass);
                    $stmt->execute();
```

I dont get any errors, but I am pretty sure the problem is in the binding parameters. I only end up getting a Document Moved - This document may be found here page.

Yes I am going to add `password_hash` ;)

Please any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't bind `uid` in the statement

Comment: 1. I fail to see where do you get *multiple* rows here. 2. You don't get errors simply because you didn't configure PHP/PDO to report them.